# Light Weight JRE

Tags: plugins, applet, java

I am creating a website which contains an applet. But we know that to run an applet in the browser we need java plugins(JRE). So my question is: Is it possible us to provide a light weight JRE directly with out going to oracle site.Note the JRE must be small size only the requirement is to run an applet.

Regards,
AlenLee MJ

Comment: Nope. Also, in order to run an applet, the client must have installed a JRE, not the server. If you're creating a website to contain an applet, I would advice you to redesign the application =\

Comment: Just curious, why are you creating applets. Its an old technology.

Comment: @abhinav: Can you jst help me to choose an appropriate technology.

Comment: What is your use case?

Comment: A Qr And Bar Code Scanner

Answer (score 2):

there is no such a thing, all you have to do is go to oracle site and install JRE.
The one who need to install JRE is client who use this applet not in server side.